# Count First number of all lists in list

Tags: python

I have a txt file and data in it like this:

```
[1, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 3]
[3, 2, 3]
```

I want to count all lists 1 numbers and write, after this count all second numbers.
Result should be like this.

1. Column

1 Result : 1

2 Result : 1

3 Result : 1

---

2. Column

1 Result : 1

2 Result : 2

3 Result : 0

I can't do it, i try many loops, may you help me pls

My code is like this

```py
from ast import literal_eval
count = 0
first = 0
second = 0
third = 0
with open("data.txt") as f:
    matrix = []
    for line in f:
        row = literal_eval(line)
        matrix.append(row)

print(matrix)
print(len(matrix))
print("-----------")
for i in matrix:
    for j in range(3):

        if i[j] == 1:
            first += 1
        elif i[j] == 2:
            second += 1
        elif i[j] == 3:
            third += 1

    print(f"1. Result {first}")
    print(f"2. Result {second}")
    print(f"3. Result {third}")
    print(f"----")
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, in the title you are asking for `sum` in the body you are asking for something else. Please edit the question and make it clear for reader

Comment: @ThePyGuy if a question lacks details or clarity, please vote to close it on that basis.

Comment: I had to squint at this for several minutes before I understood.

Comment: Sorry, i edit title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` to convert the columns to rows so you can use `count` on them

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 1],
          [2, 1, 3],
          [3, 2, 3]]

for t in zip(*matrix):
    print(f"1. Result {t.count(1)}")
    print(f"2. Result {t.count(2)}")
    print(f"3. Result {t.count(3)}")
    print(f"----")
```

Output

```
1. Result 1
2. Result 1
3. Result 1
----
1. Result 1
2. Result 2
3. Result 0
----
1. Result 1
2. Result 0
3. Result 2
```

---

Comment: I want to count columns and need to find how many 1, 2 and 3 i have in all file.

Comment: @onurhanozer this what this code does. You aleady have the file part.

Comment: Ok understand now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are able to properly read the text file as list of list of numbers, you can first get the number of rows and columns in the data, then find the required sum iterating these rows, and cols, you can accomplish it in List-Comprehension:

```py
rows, cols = len(l), len(l[0])
sums=[sum([l[i][j] for i in range(rows)]) for j in range(cols)]
# sums
[6, 5, 7]
```